# CSS hovering over span within span not applying effect correctly.

Tags: html, css, hover

Given the following html:

```
<span class="tag1">cars<span class="tag2">sports</span></span>
```

If I want each individual tag to change color when I hover over them, I am not sure how to make them hover independent of each other.

If I hover over tag2, I am also technically hovering over tag1, since it contains tag2, so both will change color, when I only want tag2 to change color in that instance. Is there a way I can do this without making them non-nested?

Answer (score 0):

Is the below solution you are looking for? Link to JSfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/5v3hpfjo/

```css
.parent,.child 
{
  float: left;
}
.parent span:hover
{
  background-color: pink;
}
.child span:hover
{
     background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
  <div class="parent">
    <span>
      cars
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>
      sports
    </span>
  </div>
```